What is causing event listener not to capture event on click?
I have a webpage with an image. When I click on the image, it opens modal. When I click on the close button, it closes the modal. However, when I click outside the modal, it doesn't close the modal. I added event listener to detect clicks but doesn't work. I tried similar related questions on stackoverflow like adding overlay over the module, it still doesn't work. I am lost. Would appreciate new ideas.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var modal = document.getElementById("imageModal");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("modalImage");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // Open modal when image is clicked
    document.querySelectorAll(".modal-trigger").forEach(function(img) {
        img.onclick = function() {
            overlay.style.display = "block";
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
    });

    // Close modal when close button is clicked
    closeButton.onclick = function() {
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        modal.style.display = "none";
    };

    // Close modal when clicking outside of modal content
    window.onclick = function(e) {
        // Close if clicking directly on the overlay
        if (e.target == overlay) {
            overlay.style.display = "none";
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    };

    // Prevent clicks inside the modal from closing it
    modal.onclick = function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent clicks inside the modal from closing it
    };
});
/* The Modal (background) */

.overlay {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); /* Semi-transparent background */
        }

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 20px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Add some padding */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption { 
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)} 
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

 .timeline-item img {
                display: block;
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
        cursor: pointer; /* Show a pointer cursor on hover */
    }

    .timeline-item img:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
        transform: scale(1.05); /* Slightly enlarge the image on hover */
    }
<div class="timeline-item" style=" left: 120px;">ABCDdgfgfhggfhg<img alt="" class="modal-trigger" src="https://compote.slate.com/images/22ce4663-4205-4345-8489-bc914da1f272.jpeg?crop=1560%2C1040%2Cx0%2Cy0&width=1280" style=" position: relative; top: 70px; width: 215px; left: -30px;" />



</div>

<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
        <div id="imageModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="modalImage" />
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
    </div>




The modal has width: 100%; height: 100%;. So it covers the whole window, there's no "outside the modal".

Your CSS says (only relevant parts shown):
.modal {
  /* ... elided ... */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* ... elided ... */
}

so it covers the whole viewport. Therefor, your window.onclick will never execute, because click's are captured by the .modal element.
Below is a version that works. I removed the window.onclick listener since it is never executed anyway and moved the if statement inside into the modal.onclick handler. Please note that I additionally changed the condition in the statement: Any click outside the image's area will close the modal. This means you can remove the closeButton.onclick handler as well.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var modal = document.getElementById("imageModal");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("modalImage");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // Open modal when image is clicked
    document.querySelectorAll(".modal-trigger").forEach(function(img) {
        img.onclick = function() {
            overlay.style.display = "block";
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
    });

    // Close modal when close button is clicked
    /*closeButton.onclick = function() {
        overlay.style.display = "none";
        modal.style.display = "none";
    };*/

    
    modal.onclick = function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent clicks inside the modal from closing it
        if (event.target !== modalImg) {
            overlay.style.display = "none";
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
});
/* The Modal (background) */

.overlay {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); /* Semi-transparent background */
        }

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 20px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Add some padding */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption { 
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)} 
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

 .timeline-item img {
                display: block;
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
        cursor: pointer; /* Show a pointer cursor on hover */
    }

    .timeline-item img:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
        transform: scale(1.05); /* Slightly enlarge the image on hover */
    }
<div class="timeline-item" style=" left: 120px;">ABCDdgfgfhggfhg<img alt="" class="modal-trigger" src="https://compote.slate.com/images/22ce4663-4205-4345-8489-bc914da1f272.jpeg?crop=1560%2C1040%2Cx0%2Cy0&width=1280" style=" position: relative; top: 70px; width: 215px; left: -30px;" />



</div>

<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
        <div id="imageModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="modalImage" />
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
    </div>



